# No var or breakable: How to "break" when a predicate is met, in an array traversal?

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, scala-collections, iterable

How would I write this programming logic into a functional method signature? I am attempting to loop/traverse an array until a condition is met, then break upon that condition. I'm mostly trying my best to avoid `var` and `breakable` from `scala.util.control.Breaks`. It makes use of a closure, in this case, `dictionary`, to check if a condition/predicate is met. The idea is that I am looping through an array until the predicate is met. I'm also avoiding converting my array to list. Would use of an array not allow me to splice the array, for example, to do pattern matching?

```
val dictionary = Array.fill(128)(false)

def isUnique(array: Array[Char]): Option[Char] = {

  // traverse each element of the array {
  //     if a character.toInt is in the dictionary, insert into dictionary 
  //        exit loop, with the character which broke the loop
  //     else
  //        set dictionary(character.toInt) to true and continue looping
  // }
}
```

Here's an example use case:

```
val word = "abcdefggghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz".toArray
val charThatBrokeIt = isUnique(word)
```

---

**Edit**: Feel free to suggest or propose other return types as well, such as a Boolean, Tuple, Case Class, or any others. `Option[Char]` might not be a good resultant value on my part. For example. I may have returned `false` in the case that loop broke out early (short-circuited) or not.

Comment: The answers there make use of `var`. I'm doing my best to avoid `var`. The only answer from that link that doesn't use var is from fresskoma, which uses lengthy tail recursive pattern matching.

Comment: If you have possible suggestions for a better question title, please let me know. They aren't duplicates.

Comment: The return type `Option[Char]` might not be an optimal type, so feel free to edit that type as well. I know there might some pros/cons to other solutions, such as wrapping the value returned into a case class which might apply or unapply on a pattern match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a `String` already acts like a collection, so you should just use `String` instead of `Array[Char]`.  Second, you can take advantage of laziness to allow short-circuiting while still splitting the algorithm into parts, using `.view`.

```scala
def breaksUnique(word: String): Option[Char] = {
  val cumulativeSets = word.view.scanLeft(Set.empty[Char]){_ + _}
  val zipped = cumulativeSets zip word
  val nonDupsDropped = zipped dropWhile {case (set, char) => !(set contains char)}
  nonDupsDropped.map{_._2}.headOption
}
```

The first two lines are written as if they process the entire word, but because they operate on a view, they are only calculated as needed.

`cumulativeSets` is a sequence of sets of every character that has been seen up to that point.  If you ran it on "abb", you would get `Set(), Set(a), Set(a,b), Set(a,b)`.  That is combined with the original word using `zip`, giving `(Set(),a), (Set(a),b), (Set(a,b),b)`.  We then just have to drop all the pairs where the character doesn't appear in the set, then return the first element that wasn't dropped.

Comment: Wow. This is a very concise, amazing solution.
I'm still breaking most of it down, but this is along the lines of something I was looking for! 
I was looking for a solution that made use of short-circuit evaluation, immutability, and a solution that cares for running-time with the use of `view`. What I love most about this solution is that you use sets and that can describe the expected function behavior more clearly. `dropWhile`, `scanLeft`, and Sets are definitely something I'm not too comfortable yet with, but you showed me a great use case!

Answer (score 1):

Early breakout always suggests recursion.

```
def isUnique(array: Array[Char]): Option[Char] = {
  def getDup(index: Int, acc: Set[Char]): Option[Char] =
    if (array.isDefinedAt(index))
      if (acc(array(index))) Some(array(index))
      else getDup(index+1, acc + array(index))
    else None
  getDup(0, Set.empty[Char])
}
```

Usage:

```
val word = "abcdefggghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz".toArray
val charThatBrokeIt = isUnique(word)
//charThatBrokeIt: Option[Char] = Some(g)
```

Comment: `Try` seems like overkill here, since you know that `getDup` will always return -1 or a valid index.

Comment: @JoePallas; It was just a concise means to wrap the result in an `Option` but, yeah, there's a better way to get there.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks. I really hope that an Option[Char] type, on my part, wasn't limiting your solution. Would there be better propositions for a resultant? I thought about returning a boolean, but I wasn't sure if that would add or reduce any more value. Since I could check for None if there was no duplicate letter.

Comment: `Option[Char]` seems to make sense to me but, ideally, a method's profile should be determined by what might be most useful/meaningful for the caller/client. Implementation issues should be secondary concerns.

Comment: The return type is okay but the method naming is problem, a method called `isUnique` should logically return `Boolean`.